# export categories in csv magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to export all categories using the script and save in the CSV file.

categories will be in the tree structure like below:

```
Root Category, sub1, subsub1, subsubsub1
Root Category, sub1, subsub1, subsubsub2
Root Category, sub1, subsub2, subsubsub1
Root Category, sub1, subsub2, subsubsub2
```

Comment: https://magento2-blog.com/magento-2-export-categories/ try this

Comment: I have used this script. but it saves the categories in the text file in the tree structure.

Comment: @VinodKumar Have you get solution of import export categories in csv ?

Comment: @VinodKumar I am also facing issue in export categories. Could you please let me know if you have get any solution of export categories in csv?
your help would be appreciated. Thanks